# Expecation of a raised random variable

Tags: probability, expectation

Let $\alpha>0$ be some scalar and $X$ a random variable.
How can I calculate $E[\alpha^X]$?

Comment: By finding the integral $\int\alpha^xP_X(dx)$ (or $\int\alpha^{X(\omega)}\mathsf P(d\omega)$).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$E\left[\alpha^X\right] = \int_{-\infty}^\infty \alpha^x f_X(x) dx, \tag{1}$$
where $f_X(x)$ is the probability density function (pdf) of $X$.

Comment: Provided of course that a PDF of $X$ exists.